# AdS/CFT at small and large central charge

Tags: ads-cft

We know that the AdS/CFT duality is a valid correspondence for large central charge (in the semi-classical limit). If this duality is valid for small central charge (in the quantum regime) is unclear.

---

It is often said that

> *a **high energy CFT state** on a torus is dual to a **Euclidean BTZ black hole spacetime** with a torus conformal structure at asymptotic infinity*.

On the other hand, there has been an explicit check (see this [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.1987)) that

> *the **Ising model CFT** on a torus is dual to the **full AdS quantum gravity theory** with a torus conformal structure at asymptotic infinity*.

This check has been performed by computing the partition functions of the Ising model CFT and the quantum gravity theory, where the partition function of the quantum gravity theory is a sum over geometries globally diffeomorphic to thermal Anti-de Sitter spacetime ( this includes the thermal Anti-de Sitter space and **the Euclidean BTZ black hole spacetime**).

---

My question is the following:

How can a CFT be dual to the BTZ spacetime in one case, and the sum over all AdS-like spacetimes in the second case? Does this have something to do with the duality at small and large central charge?

Comment: I don't see the inconsistency, if the Ising-model-on-a-torus *at high temperature* is dual to a sum *dominated by* the black hole geometry.

Comment: I see. The higher the temperature, the higher the dominance by the BTZ spacetime. This would seem to imply that CFT on a torus with *small circumference* is dual to *semiclassical gravity*?